# Executing get - Exception thrown for selenium standalone with chrome driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

## Intro

I have selenium standalone running:

```
java -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

I have [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) at the same working directory.

I create chrome session:

```
curl -XPOST -d'{"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome"}},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome"}}' http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session
{"state":null,"sessionId":"d33f687e-62c2-4147-aab1-a1c1bba29aed","hCode":1317400713,"value":{"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"chrome":{"userDataDir":"/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.w26Qkk"},"takesHeapSnapshot":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"handlesAlerts":true,"hasTouchScreen":true,"version":"57.0.2987.133","platform":"LINUX","browserConnectionEnabled":false,"nativeEvents":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"webdriver.remote.sessionid":"d33f687e-62c2-4147-aab1-a1c1bba29aed","locationContextEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":true,"browserName":"chrome","takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true},"class":"org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response","status":0}
```

I see chrome is opened with message:

```
You are using an unsupported command-line flag: -ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer.
```

[image: chrome is opened]

## Problem

Then I try to open an url in chrome:

```
curl -XPOST -d'{"url":"http://stackoverflow.com"}' http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/d33f687e-62c2-4147-aab1-a1c1bba29aed/url
```

I get [response](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=79c5961a525302a9283a304eec6eaf26)

And chrome browser does **NOT** open the URL.

Selenium stand alone output for get URL command:

```
08:32:33.405 INFO - Executing: [get: http://stackoverflow.com])
08:32:34.255 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"5244.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 64 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'np', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.2.0-27-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.w26Qkk}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=57.0.2987.133, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 6d5d29b199469d31ecf04abcfbea2493
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:364)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.get(EventFiringWebDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ChangeUrl.call(ChangeUrl.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ChangeUrl.call(ChangeUrl.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
08:32:34.288 WARN - Exception: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"5244.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 64 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'np', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.2.0-27-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.w26Qkk}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=57.0.2987.133, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 6d5d29b199469d31ecf04abcfbea2493
```

## With firefox it works

The same actions work well for firefox and geckodriver:

```
curl -XPOST -d'{"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox"}},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox"}}' http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session
```

and

```
curl -XPOST -d'{"url":"http://stackoverflow.com"}' http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/73835d43-d566-4e88-bcab-1f45ff4db129/url
```

And I see stackoverflow.com opened in firefox browser.

## Versions

Google chrome and chrome driver versions:

```
google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 57.0.2987.133 

 ./chromedriver -version
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304) on port 9515
```

Operating system:
Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your stacktrace, you are using *an old `ChromeDriver 2.9`*. But, according to the [`ChromeDriver` downloads page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), for Chrome 57, you should be using [`ChromeDriver 2.29`](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.29/).

Comment: that's right. Using ChromeDriver 2.29 solved my problem!